# How to rename the downloaded file with extension

Tags: php, download, rename

I am able to rename the downloaded attachments with `image1`,`image2`.... n so on.

but it is only displaying a `blank file`, and renaming with the name... but how to give extension to display the attachment?

I am using `rename` function which is working for my code,

how will I add extension?

`rename($image, $all);`

(renaming downloaded file with the above mentioned names)

Answer (score 0):

Try to just give extension to your name:

```
rename($image, $newtname.'.jpeg')
```

or

```
rename($image, $newtname.'.png')
```

etc.

Comment: no it is displaying the blank file with the names image1.jpg, image2.jpg but not reading the actual file

Comment: Did u check that the file have its content before renaming?

Comment: am able to download it and its readable, but while renaming how vl i add extension to it

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
rename($image, $all.'.jpg'); // you can change to any extension you like
```